# Failed to install MyApp.apk on device '037c6206441f83d7': Not a directory

Tags: android, eclipse, adb

I'm trying to run/debug my app, using Eclipse, on my device with ICS (Asus Transformer TF101 - rooted). But i get following error:

```
   Uploading MyApp.apk onto device '037c6206441f83d7'
   Failed to install MyApp.apk on device '037c6206441f83d7': Not a directory
   com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: Not a directory
   Launch canceled!
```

I tried running/debugging other apps, also sample apps, but still got same error, but every thing works on emulator, of course I got USB debug on. Before update I was able to run everything normally, is it possible that I have messed up something while flashing my rom/rooting? But on the other hand, I think that my device works fine...

Comment: possible if some of the required directories (like `/data/app/`) were removed or have bad permissions set.

Comment: Yes, sounds like a broken system.  For example, you may have set the application install location to a partition which doesn't exist.  You may need support from whoever provided your system image / customizations / rooting instructions.  android.stackexchange would be more appropriate.

Comment: can you use command line to navigate to the bin directory of your project and run adb install -r appname.apk

Comment: @DrakeClarris when I'm using command: `adb install -r MyApp.apk`
I got this error:
`failed to copy 'RemoteFileSharing.apk' to '/data/local/tmp/MyApp.apk': Not a directory`

Comment: Does your phone have the directory /data/local/tmp ? If not, mkdir.

Comment: There is a file tmp, but looks like its not a directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved this problem, looks like I have really messed up something while flashing new rom/rooting. There was some problem with `/data/local/tmp` directory, and I have used my `ClockworkMod Recovery` to `wipe /data/ (factory reset)` and now it works perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Simply go to this folder with a file explorer with root privileges, delete the file tmp and create a FOLDER with same name.
additionally you can use adb shell to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I just run `adb shell` on linux then run `rm -rf /data/local/tmp/MY_APK_DIR` and problem was solved.